# How to create a visual selection marker of a hovering element in HTML/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I basically want to implement a feature to show the HTML element selection marker while the mouse is hovering on it. Why I need this is because I am trying to show the hovering target element's bounds while user's dragging other elements over the same to indicate the location where the user would drop it off.

I just tried a lot of search on stackoverflow and google, but unfortunately I didn't find any similar answers to this question.

I actually have some preliminary ideas to implement this, is to dynamically add and remove css class to the hovering target element, but how to compose the css class? do I need to style the element bounds by using pseudo class, eg. :before or :after? What I want is probably a blinking caret with customized styles or whatever is obvious to the users to indicate the drop location.

And another derived question is, to implement this visual selection marker would probably pollute the original html. What if I don't want to pollute the html, how can I achieve this? use shadow dom? and if so, how to shadow the whole document?

Here paste some of my code snippets:

```
    document.addEventListener("dragover", OnDragOver, false);
    document.addEventListener("dragleave", OnDragLeave, false);
    document.addEventListener("drop", OnDrop, false);

    var OnDragOver = function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      //to show the visual selection marker
    }

    var OnDragLeave = function(ev) {

    }

    var OnDrop = function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      data = TranslateHtml(data);
      ev.target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", data);
    }
```

Comment: You want to show the boundaries of the element another draggable element is hovering over? Or you want to show the boundaries of the element the mouse is hovering over while *not dragging an element*?

Comment: Hi Dave, maybe my question is obscure, I actually wanted to simulate a blink caret with styling on it close to the hovering target, to indicate the location to drop the dragged element.

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically add a CSS class to the element you are dragging over, using the `:after` content to display a caret indicating the drop position:

```js
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.innerHTML);
});

document.addEventListener("dragover", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.target.classList.add("dragover");
});

document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(ev) {
  ev.target.classList.remove("dragover");
});

document.addEventListener("drop", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.target.classList.remove("dragover");
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", data);
});
```

```css
.dragover:after {
  content: "";  
  border: thin black dotted;
  animation: blink .75s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Sample Document</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<div draggable="true">Drag me!</div>
```

Note that your original code won't work unless you move the `var OnDrag...` declarations above the `.addEventListener()` calls. Otherwise their values are undefined when adding them as event listeners.

Comment: From the question, I gather that he wants to use JS since his cursor will be over the element being dragged, so simple CSS won't do the job

Comment: I updated my answer with your suggestion in mind. Thanks!

Comment: thanks le_m very much for the prompt answer. I actually can show the boundaries for the hovering target by adding a css class to it to draw the borders and shadows. whereas now I want to show the location (visualize the location) before or after the hovering target, probably so called a simulated caret?

Comment: Would you mind rewording your question then? You might get more useful answers

Comment: @le_m ah yeah, this seems more relevant now

Comment: @Jonathan I edited my answer. Is this what you have in mind?